# how to query a partitioned table in bigquery from datastudio

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, partition, looker-studio

This topic was covered for tableau here:

[How to query a partitioned table in BigQuery from Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569572/how-to-query-a-partitioned-table-in-bigquery-from-tableau)

but I don't think you can insert parameters into datastudio yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating Data Sources you have option to create a custom query, and also opt for Legacy/Standard SQL.

[image]

Comment: this works to add _PARTITIONTIME as a variable, but it doesn't let you use the calendar filter to actually select individual partitions.  You will always end up pulling the entire table unless you hard card the partitiontime flag in the where statement (but then you dont get to select your date range using the calendar filter in data studio)

Comment: so I assume that PT field exposed as a field, can be setup just as a regular colum, so the DataStudio query builder can pick it up and use as the date column, I am right?

Comment: You can express it as a field, but if you then go to GBQ and look at what is run you will see that it wraps it and pulls from the entire table and then filters down to your dates, rather than just pulling from the selected partitions.

In the link I provided for the original question they do this for Tableau, but in Tableau you can add parameters which allow for a dynamic query instead of just wrapping the original query to make a subquery....I haven't found a way to do this in datastudio yet though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom query](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en#custom_query) for your connection to BigQuery. Rather than picking a specific table, provide a query such as:

```
SELECT *, _PARTITIONTIME AS timestamp
FROM YourPartitionedTable;
```

Support for [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) with this connector was recently launched, and although I can't seem to find a documentation page, it should be possible to enable for the query as well.

Comment: but it will always wrap your custom query and make it a subquery, so when you use the calendar filter in datastudio to select your aliased _PARTITIONTIME it will first pull the entire table (instead of just the selected partitions).

Comment: I answered your question, which was how to query a partitioned table from Data Studio. You did not ask anything about calendar filters.

Comment: The question was how do I do what they did in tableau in datastudio and take advantage of the partitions...not taking advantage of the partitions kind of defeats the whole purpose.